# Simulating two-body decays in the specific direction

Tags: kinematics

How to simulate the 2-body decay of some particle with mass $m$ moving with the given 4-momentum $p^{\mu}$ into two particles 1,2 with masses $m_{1}, m_{2}$ such that, say, the particle 1 will have the polar angle from $\theta_{1}$ to $\theta_{2}$ in the lab frame, and also find a probability that the particle 1 will flight into this direction?

The brute-force approach is, obviously, to sample randomly many decays at the rest frame, then boost to the lab frame, and then select only those where the particle 1 flies in the given direction. However, it is computationally expensive and very inefficient, especially if $\theta_{2}-\theta_{1}$ is tiny.

Probably, it may be possible to derive the relation between the polar and azimuthal angles at the rest frame of the decaying particle and its lab frame. Then, it may be possible to sample randomly $\theta_{\text{rest}},\phi_{\text{rest}}$, while the probability is
$$
P_{\text{pointing}} = \int_{\theta_{1}<\theta_{\text{lab}}<\theta_{2}} \frac{d\Omega_{\text{rest}}}{4\pi}
$$

However, so far, I failed to do such a clear relation.